# IE 9, 10: div structure and events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have a not so complicated `<div>` structure, which breaks event handlers in IE < 11 (other major browsers like Chrome and Firefox are working).

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="layer">
        <div id="layer1">
            <img src="http://sopos.org/olli/blindbild.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
        <div id="controller"></div>
        <input id="slider" type="range" />
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnailer">
        <img src="http://sopos.org/olli/blindbild-thumb.png" />
        <div id="viewArea"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the registered event handlers:

```js
$(function () {
    var stopPropagation = function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    $('#controller').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        console.log('controller mousedown');
    });
    $('#controls').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
        console.log('controls mousewheel');
        stopPropagation(e);
        return false;
    });
    $('#thumbnailer').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('thumbnailer clicked');
    });
    $('#viewArea').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('viewarea click');
        stopPropagation(e);
        return false;
    });
    $('#viewArea').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        console.log('viewarea mousedown');
        stopPropagation(e);
        return false;
    });
    $('#slider').on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('slider change');
        stopPropagation(e);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The main problem seems to be CSS positioning and sizing:

```css
#layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: -175.813008130081px;
    left: -578.615px;
    width: 1421px;
    height: 875px;
}
#layer1, #layer1 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#thumbnailer {
    background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 123px;
}
#thumbnailer img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#viewArea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 81px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 56%;
    height: 56%;
}
#controller {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

In IE < 11, any click or `mousedown` on `viewArea` remains unhandled; instead, an event on `thumbnailer` is fired.  Similarily, the `mousewheel` event on `controls` and the `mousedown` on `controller` don't get handled.  The `mousewheel` event get's fired when the cursor is over the `slider` element, though.

This strange behaviour seems to be rooted in the size of the two images.  However, my application needs to display bigger images in a relative small container (hence `overflow: hidden` set).

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aohab3jh/13/) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that IE < 11 doesn't trigger events on empty `<div>`.  Adding a transparent `<img>` to the div solves the problem:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="layer">
        <div id="layer1">
            <img src="http://sopos.org/olli/blindbild.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="controls">
        <div id="controller">
           <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        </div>
        <input id="slider" type="range" />
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnailer">
        <img src="http://sopos.org/olli/blindbild-thumb.png" />
        <div id="viewArea">
           <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```